# export scraped data to CSV format with rowwise headers

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, scrapy

Scrapy writes data into a CSV file column wise by default ie. one field /column. How do I write the data Row wise, ie. horizontally wherein first cell of a row will be name of the field.

I went through the [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter), but there i'snt anything using which I can change the format in which data in CSV is written

### Update:

**How I'm getting right now:**

products,price
TV,25000
refrigerator,15000

**This is how I want it:**

products,tv,refrigerator
price,25000,15000

**Why I want it that way?**
I'm continuing the data extraction process done by someone else earlier, and 65% process has been finished. So this is to maintain consistency with the format.

Comment: could you explain with sample data the format you want?

Comment: personally, I would export as CSV and then write a small conversion script in Python with `csv` (see [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader))

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV file is large and you want to avoid loading the data into Python lists or dictionaries, you can do this:

```
infile = "/path/to/input_file.csv"
outfile = "/path/to/output_file.csv"
with open(infile, 'r') as source:
    num_fields = len(source.readline().split(','))
    source.seek(0) # Go back to beginning
    with open(outfile, 'w') as dest:
        for n in range(num_fields):
            for input_line in source:
                dest.write(input_line.split(',')[n] + ',')
            source.seek(0)
            dest.write('\b\n') # remove trailing comma
```

Otherwise you can just load everything up:

```
infile = "/path/to/input_file.csv"
outfile = "/path/to/output_file.csv"
with open(infile, 'r') as source:
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in source]
with open(outfile, 'w') as dest:
    for n in range(len(data[0])):
        dest.writeline(','.join(line[n] for line in data))
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem isnt about large file. file is small. but the issue is that there are multiple files. Its like, there are about a million pages, and I save the data from each page in a different csv.